# How can i find the index of variables of Nginx about gRPC?

Tags: nginx

Nginx is a great tool for proxy, and we can use it for gRPC proxy simply.

When I change the `log_format` of gRPC request, [grpc_gateway.conf](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nginx-gists/87ed942d4ee9f7e7ebb2ccf757ed90be/raw/f96b46b5acbdd775fd4132743dc98e82eaad93b1/grpc_gateway.conf) refer to the sample. The variable `$grpc_status` look like grpc-special variable, but where can I find all the variable for grpc-relate variable ?

[Alphabetical index of variables](https://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html) is the offical list of `log_format` variables but there is nothing about gRPC...

Comment: There are none of additional variables in `ngx_http_grpc_module`. The `$grpc_status` variable is derived via [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) directive from the [`$upstream_trailer_grpc_status`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_trailer_) variable.

Comment: Oh , you are right. Thanks.

Comment: an other thing , where is `upstream_trailer_grpc_status`  defined?

Comment: It is one of `$upstream_trailer_<name>` variables, I give you a link already. As I understand, nginx gets an according field (`grpc_status`) from the gRPC message. I'm not familiar with gRPC.